# Apache Jena not inferencing individual type based on data property

Tags: owl, jena, ontology, inference

I used Protégé to create a very simple OWL ontology with

- a class `Person`
- a class `Adult` subclass of intersection between class `Person` and restriction  `age exactly 1 xsd:integer[> 17]`
- a class `Minor` subclass of intersection between class `Person` and restriction `age exactly 1 xsd:integer[< 18]`
- a data property `age` with domain union of `Adult` and `Minor` and range `xsd:integer`.
- two individuals: `Child` with age 12 and `Grandfather` with age 70.

My goal was to perform inference on the model and infer the correct type of the individuals depending on the value of their data property age.

Following [Jena's APIs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#OWLexamples) I wrote the following code to create an inferred model from this ontology, expecting the reasoner to infer the statement `Child rdf:type Minor`.

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
        FileManager fileManager = FileManager.getInternal();
        model.read(fileManager.open(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("/persone.owl")).toString()), null);

        Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner().bindSchema(model);
        InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, model);

        Resource minor = infModel.getResource("http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Minor");
        Resource child = infModel.getResource("http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child");

        printStatements(infModel, child, null, null);

        if (infModel.contains(child, RDF.type, minor)) {
            System.out.println("Child is type Minor -> Inferenced correctly");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to inference Child's type correctly");
        }
```

But the type is not inferenced and the output is the following:

```
 - (<http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child> <http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#age> '12'^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer)
 - (<http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child> rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual)
 - (<http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child> rdf:type owl:Thing)
 - (<http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child> owl:sameAs <http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child>)
 - (<http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child> rdf:type rdfs:Resource)
 - (<http://www.semanticweb.org/lorenzo/ontologies/2023/5/Persone#Child> rdf:type 2449192a-2fc0-426e-a3ab-f9ef16f56342)
Failed to inference Child's type correctly
```

Comment: Does Protege infer what you need? 1. `Child` should be equivalent to that intersection or be a superclass rather than subclass. 2. `age` should be functional and/or `Child` should be declared using `some` instead of `exactly 1`.

Comment: I doubt that data property facet restrictions are covered by the built-in Jena reasoners - you can use Pellet (resp. its fork Openllet for latest Jena) and see if this works

Comment: also, using "exactly" usually suffers from the Open World Assumption in OWL

Comment: It works fine with Openllet. Now I tried to change the domain of the age property to Person instead of (Adult or Minor), but the inference works only if the restrictions are applied to subclasses as equivalentOf instead of subClassOf. What could be the problem?